# Unit Tests Pass In Webstorm But Fail In Terminal - File System Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

my project is running on Node. I am using jest to write my unit tests. All my tests are working besides the ones that are using the File System module. I have posted more data below. Does anyone know why the tests that use my readFile function that has the 'fs' module in it fail in terminal but pass inside WebStorm IDE? All help is welcome, thanks! Also, that error isn't correct, I debugged through and I see my file being read/loaded in so I'm not sure why it's saying it can't find or open it.

Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './files/history.txt'`

```
  2 | 
  3 | function readFile(file) {
> 4 |     return fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    |               ^
  5 | 
  6 | }
  7 |
```

Test Expect:

```
expect(readFile(testFile)).toEqual(fileContent);
```

File System Module

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readFile(file) {
    return fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');

}
```

Comment: Your current directory is wrong.

Comment: How can it be wrong, im passing it into the function. When I debug i can also see that the file is being read in perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is some weird behavior happening with readFileSync. "It seems fs.readFileSync is relative to the directory where the script is invoked from, instead of where the script actually is."

This is what I did to fix it. Hope this helps, thanks!

```
function readFile(file) {
    return fs.readFileSync(`./files/${file}`, 'utf8');
}
```

Comment: That's the reason why we use `path.join(__dirname, file)` in such cases. Relying on current working directory can make your scripts mysteriously fail on some conditions.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `readFileSync()`; it's how relative paths work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths